# Analytics on test site + live site

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

We are deploying `.war` servlet,s on test and live.

I can't be bothered putting conditional code to include analytics or not, can I use same code on both sites, and will analytics ONLY show the stats for the live site? (as that's the registered domain)

Will it exclude test hits?

Comment: Can't be bothered? You could have done it in the time it took you to write this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you leave on your Analytic test site: you have to test that the tracking works.

The conventional approach is to create an Analytics [profile](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55486) which takes into account only the test version and an other that excluded this version. You can do this thanks to the [filters](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55494) (based on your host or IP) in the Analytics interface.

Comment: Same concept as here, except a profile for each: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336711/

Answer (score 1):

You could use location.host to determine whether the site is in development or not.

```
if(location.host=='mysite.com') {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```

Or maybe the inverse of that code:

```
if(location.host!='localhost') {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```

Comment: I've used similar code:
`if (!/testHost|localhost/.test(window.location.hostname)) _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`

Answer (score 0):

Yea just compare the hostname. Like this:

```
<script>if ('example.com' === window.location.hostname){
    // Google Analytics - mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet - Change UA-XXXXX-X to your ID:
    var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-XXXXX-X"],["_trackPageview"]];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
}</script>
```

If you're using `www.` then check that too.